# How to scale up an EC2 web service from staging to production

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to server-side development and hoping someone can fill in the blanks or recommend appropriate tutorials to help me scale up a staging web service built using Node.js v4.2.4 on a single AWS EC2 t2.micro instance to a production environment resilient to down time.

In order to avoid any downtime and to make it optimal for users in multiple regions (say Europe and USA for now), I believe I need to do the following.

1. Create EC2 instances for both Europe and USA running exactly the same web service.
2. Create an Elastic Load Balancer which points to both EC2 instances so that if one goes down or experiences high load, it will automatically route to the other.  Downed instances should automatically restart if the instance is alive.
3. Create a Cloudfront that points to the ELB.  Both EC2 instances should be able to automatically push new content that I want cached to Cloudfront.
4. Create an EC2 Node.js database that holds user authentication data.  I'm currently playing around with MongoDB but open to other DBs.

Questions:

A. Does this look correct so far?

B. Does it make sense to host the user database on separate EC2 instances to the actual web service?

C. So that the user database has maximum uptime, I expect I also need to host it on multiple instances.  How should I share the database across instances?  Is this what sharding is for?  When a new account is created, I would like the new db entry to automatically appear in both copies of the database.

D. I eventually plan to support https.  Is it sensible to add support for this at the very end or could that cause problems?

E. Anything else I've missed or need to consider?

Comment: An ELB can only point to instances in the same region. It can't route traffic to both US and EU regions. You could possibly do this using Route53.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on to iSkore's answer:

**B**

Isolating the DB from the EC2 instance provides better control over the operations like scaling up storage and to have a good idea in case of any issues to figure out where exactly the problem is.

**C**

For EC2 instances located in one region can connect to RDS(in same region say US N.Virginia) by adding security group to RDS with inbound rule allowing the EC2 ip or an EC2 security group for access.

If your application has a user base that is spread out all over the planet, you can use Cross Region Read Replicas to serve read queries from an AWS region that is close to the user.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cross-region-read-replicas-for-amazon-rds-for-mysql/

**D**

HTTPS requires generating and adding certificates though.It's easy.

**E**
Anytime

Comment: Too add to the pile of "it isn't a good idea NOT to use a DB cluster" - Bottomline, you have to have a DB somewhere. ELB obviously can't have a universal DB cause its not a server, just a traffic distributer. Lets say you went ahead with putting it on a single region's server/ server fleet; you would have to replicate from fleet to fleet OR tap into one big server fleet. Very costly on server processing, memory, traffic, throughput, your pocket book, etc.   -   It would be a good idea to start by using Kinesis to take in the PUT information then having Lambda do 3 Put requests to region A-B-C

Answer (score -1):

#### A

Yes, you can do this but you don't want to point a load balancer to two different regions. You'll want to have one ELB in us-east/west and one in Europe. If you have a single instance attached to the ELB, then it will dispatch requests to that instance. As for scaling, I would recommend scaling out for this. It sounds like - based on the question - you are looking for high availablity.

**Scaling out** - booting up more t2.micro instances attached to one ELB. So you scale outward from 1 to 3

**Scaling up** - changing your t2.micro to a medium or something of higher caliber is "scaling up"

If you want better availability for a website, scale out

If you want better compute power for a web app, scale up

So A really depends on what you want to do.

#### B

Sounds like a perfect example of using AWS's database cluster. I would highly recommend Dynamo DB for this, it's so much easier and cheaper to use a cluster - separate from your servers. Dynamo is perfect for user authentication and you should store the individuals session information in ElastiCache - really good if one server goes down, their session is saved.

#### C

Definitely use a database cluster like Dynamo or RDS

#### D

No problem, just make your HTTP fall over to HTTPS

#### E

Please feel free to inbox me with any questions. Always willing to help

Comment: How are servers in different regions going to be able to connect to the same database? Route53 has nothing to do with HTTPS... HTTPS would be best handled at the ELB.

Comment: Yeah, you might want to look into what Route53 does. It just handles domain names, not ports or protocols. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176969/how-to-forward-http-request-to-https-in-amazon-route53

Comment: Thanks iSkore, that's very helpful.  So, for fault tolerance, I could scale out within each region to have an instance in each availability zone and point the ELB to each of those? I guess that would reduce my need to scale up as well.  Does this mean I shouldn't concern myself with Cross-Zone Load Balancing?  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/enable-disable-crosszone-lb.html